# I am using ffmpeg for overlaying a image on live stream. How can i scale accoring to the widht of my screen so that it fits completely

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, http-live-streaming

I am scaling the output from complex filter to different standard resolutions using the -s flag but the result is that the video does not fit completely into my output screen. How can i scale the different outputs dynamically according to the screen. Here is my command.

```
ffmpeg  -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/show/$2 -i $overlayUrl  -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=iw:ih[ovr][base];[base][ovr] overlay=0:0, split=4[a][b]" -async 1 -vsync -1 -map 0:a -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 256k -b:a 32k -s 640x360 -tune zerolatency -r 60 -preset  veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://$rtmpoutput/$2_low -map 0:a -map "[b]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 768k -b:a 96k -s 640x480 -tune zerolatency -r 60 -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://$rtmpoutput/$2_mid code here
```

Comment: What is the width x height of your screen resolution?

Comment: It is not fixed..it could be played on different types of mobile phones...my intent is that the output should fit according to the screen size..currently there is little bit of shrinkage observed in my phone as an example

Answer (score 0):

Your output has to match the aspect ratio of the screen resolution. Only practical solution is to provide a best guess to match the most common screen size of your viewers. The others will have letterbox/pillarbox to fit the screen.